# Frobenius theorem: a variant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In a physics article I am reading [1] the author uses the following result, which he named Frobenius theorem:

If a vector field $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies

$$F \cdot (\nabla \times F) = 0,\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(A)}$$

denoting scalar product and vector product in this order, then there exists scalar fields $\lambda$ and $V$ such that $F = -\lambda \nabla V$.

The only relevant Frobenius theorem I can think of is the one in differential calculus but it is about linear PDEs whereas the equation (A) is quadratic in $F$. Thus I failed to find the connection. Did I miss something? Or is there another Frobenius theorem?

[1] H Urbantke, Force fields in which all orbits are planar, European Journal of Physics 7 (1986), 157

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed a lot of cosmetically different "Frobenius theorem"s around. You shouldn't be thinking of the $F \cdot \nabla \times F = 0$ as the first-order PDE here - rather, it is the involutivity condition.

One convenient formulation of Frobenius is the following:

> If $\omega$ is a differential one-form satisfying $\omega \wedge d\omega = 0$, then locally we can find smooth functions $f,g$ such that $\omega = f\,d g$.

Letting $\omega = F^\flat$ be the one-form corresponding to $F$, we can translate from three-dimensional vector calculus to exterior calculus: we have $$F \cdot (\nabla \times F) dV = \langle \omega, \star\,d \omega \rangle dV = \omega \wedge d \omega = 0$$ and thus there exist $f,g$ such that $\omega = f\,dg$ and thus $F = f\nabla g$.